Logical replication overwrite target column
I am trying to understand the logical replication behavior . Please find the below scenario

logical replication is set
target  column2 updated (update t1 set column2='abc' where id=1)
source column1 updated (update t1 set column1=123 where id=1)
target update column2 is overwritten by source

Is this logical replication behavior? As column1 only updated but still it overwritten the target column2

It'll replicate the entire row.

Yes, that is how logical replication behaves, unless the modified column is part of the replica identity of the table.
You better don't modify any data that logical replication might modify.

Thanks for the clarification @Laurenz Albe.  Do we have any transaction level option available instead of record level replication, to fulfill my requirement as we need changes in target too. I mean at least outside of vanilla postgres

I don't think there is a remedy for that. How should the subscriber know that something has been updated locally.?
